# the standover height on my bike is a but tall. I can touch the ground, but I touch the top tube as well. Any ideas?

Tags: size

My dad recently bought me a new bike. I am 158 cm tall, and the bike is 53 size frame. I can comfortably ride it (without cleat pedals), but when I stop/finish my ride and try to get off the bike it is a bit of a hassle, as it is a kind of big for me. I can touch the ground when standing over the bike, but I don't know how it is going to be with cleats. When I stand over the bike, I touch the top tube. :/ Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. What exactly do you call "stack"? Do you mean the top tube of the frame? Do you touch it with your crotch or your sit bones?

Comment: "When I stand, I touch the stack " stack = top tube of the frame, right? 
I have the feeling the frame is of a shape that is too high for you (not necessarily too big, arm and leg measures can be good).
Usually you touch the floor with one foot, not with both. Do you still touch the frame when standing on one foot?

Comment: A size 49-51 would fit you better I think.

Comment: BTW these sizes often means something else with various manufacturers. My main bike is size 49 and I am 174 cm. No, it is not way too small., it is marketed for people with 164-179 cm. Just the top tube is sloped so the seat tube is shorter. The effective top tube length is actually 536 mm.

Comment: Sounds like the frame is way too big. When standing flat footed with both feet on the ground your private parts shouldn’t touch the frame: https://www.bestelectricbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Standover-height-2-1.jpg

Comment: It would be relevant to know how old you are. If you still expect to grow a few centimetres, it makes more sense to keep a slightly oversized bike.

Answer (score 1):

### The bike is too big for you

At 158cm (5'2" for our American viewers), you really should be on a 50cm frame size (or 49 - 51cm depending on brand). That being said, you don't necessarily *have* to move to a smaller size. You say you can comfortably ride the bike at it's current size, but getting off is challenging. It might help to review your dismount technique. The proper (and easy) way to get off a bike follows these steps:

1. slow down almost to a stop
2. take *one* foot off the pedal
3. stop and place that foot on the ground
4. shift your weight onto that foot
5. swing your other leg *backwards and over the saddle*
6. put both feet on the ground.

You now should be standing next to your bike holding the handlebars.

If this solves your problem dismounting, and you continue to ride without discomfort, then you're fine on the bike. If not, you may want to consider getting a bike that fits you a bit better.

Comment: One still risks an unpleasant experience or even an injury when having to dismount quickly and ending up hitting the top tube. Painful!

Comment: I wouldn't call this “the proper” way to dismount. There are multiple equally valid ways to dismount. If one is “the proper one”, I'd say it's leaving one foot on the pedal and _immediately_ swinging the other leg over the rear wheel, then stepping on the ground with that other foot and only at the end taking the first foot off the pedal. Particularly advantageous if the bike is a bit big, because staying on the pedal gives you some extra height to get the leg over the saddle and wheel easier. The tricky part is that you need to keep the balance while dismounting.